# Move or copy E-Mails from user mailbox to shared mailbox by API – Microsoft 365?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, office365api, outlook-web-app, outlook-api

I need to copy or move Emails from a user mailbox to a shared mailbox.
Per Graph API this case is not possible:

[message: copy - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/graph/api/message-copy?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

[message: move - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

How to handle this case? Are any other APIs for move / copy available? Maybe some Exchange Web Services (EWS) APIs that I don’t know?
In OWA this feature is available…. Which API use OWA for this case?

OR

How to import an EML file (exporting E-Mail – possible by API) to a shared mailbox?

Answer (score 3):

The EWS Move and Copy operations do support moving items between mailboxes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange you can also do an import of MIME messages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange or use ExportItem and UploadItem to do a full fidelity copy of a Message (useful if you where trying to copy between two different m365 tenants)

Comment: But can you authenticate against Exchange Online with EWS? It seems EWS only support Basic Authentication and it was decommissioned October 2020....or I'm I missing something? See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/) announcement

Comment: You can use oauth in EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oaut, basic authentication was disabled. If your building new apps you should use the Graph API if you can as EWS maybe removed in the future.